# What part of speech is "alight" in "set alight"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

In the clause *it was set alight*, is *alight*

1. acting as **adverb** and modifying *was set*
2. an **adjective** and modifying *it*; or
3. something else entirely that I'm missing.

I'm fairly certain that *set alight* isn't a phrasal verb so I'm a little stumped.

Comment: I've made it a little easier to read, but I can't do anything about the last sentence.

Comment: My dictionary (NOED) says that usage is an *adverb*.  What does your dictionary say?  (Officially, I should have withheld my answer until you gave yours.)

Comment: @user152022 It's simply an agentless passive clause with "was" as the main verb, "set" as past participle and "alight" an adjective. The active version would be "X set it alight".

Comment: The fact that a corresponding simplex verb (ignite) exists shows that the MWV status of _set alight_ should not be lightly discounted. The adverb interpretation shows the need for a clearer definition of adverbials (*set it in an alight sort of way); it should be discounted. But the link-like verb plus resultative adjective interpretation is also a strong candidate (cf it is alight; he fell/is asleep). It will take someone to decide which is the stronger claim (and then someone else to disagree).

Answer (score 2):

> It was set alight.

I would understand *alight* here as an adjective describing *it* and acting syntactically as a resultative Predicate Complement to the verb *set*: [something] caused *it* to be *alight*.

Comment: Yes; a better way of looking at it is in the active, as the passive is just a rearrangement of that: He set it alight. Alight is acting as an adjectival object complement.

Comment: I would consider it an adverb modifying *set*.  Though one might also argue that the verb is *alight* and *set* is a "helper verb".

Comment: @StoneyB It's just the agentless passive version of the active "X set it alight". "It was set alight" has "was" as main verb, "set" as past participle and "alight" as adjective.

Comment: @BIllJ Quite so.